# How do I go about having stuff licensed differently in a project licensed under a different license?

Tags: license-compatibility, agpl-3.0, relicensing, attribution, cc-by-sa

Suppose my project A is licensed under AGPL v3.

Now I choose to include stuff (a filter list actually) from different sources, which are licensed under GPLv2, CC-BY 4.0, and I have combined them in a single (pickle) file.

How should I go about it? Do I need to show every addition, deletion, etc. to the list? Or just providing the pickled file (having the python set) is enough with GPLv2 license provided with the file?

Comment: Is your list actually a copyrightable work?

Comment: What do you mean by "a filter list"? Is a filter list something that affects the contents of your project somehow (like a list of dependencies that are automatically copied in), or is it simply a piece of code that is part of your project?

Comment: Nah its just a bad words filter